# How to call an string extension method on a DataField in BoundField element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, extension-methods

Imagine that I introduced an extension method on string type called Shorten() which gets only the first 50 characters and returns it.

If I want to call this method on a GridView's bound field, what is the simplest way of calling it so that on screen I see the shorten version of the message.

```
<!-- TODO: How to call .Shorten() extension method on the ItemDescription in markup: --!>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Items" DataField="ItemDescription"...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that column a template column:

```
<itemtemplate>
<asp:label id="lblItemDesc" runat="server" Text='<%=string.Format(Eval("ItemDescription").ToShorten()))%>' />
</itemtemplate>
```

And make sure ToShorten takes an object, not a string since `Eval` returns object.

*Above code not tested but pretty sure is very close.

Another alternative:

Modify your class and add a `ItemDescriptionShorten` property that would be like this:

```
public string ItemStringDescriptionShorten { get {return ItemDescription.ToShortern();}}
```

Now bind to that property instead of  `ItemDescription`

Answer (score 1):

in the top of the .aspx file, import the namespace in which the class that contains your extension method is:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="your namespace" %>
```

and then:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Items">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ItemDescription")).Shorten() %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```